# Replacing trigger procedure without deleting triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I have trigger procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

    // Do something :-)

    RAISE NOTICE 'Done';

RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It is used for auditing and every single table in my DB have trigger which calls the procedure.

What I'm trying to do is to remove "raise notice" line - seems to be simple, but it is not.. I tried to insert new procedure to database without the line, thinking that "create od **REPLACE**" would do the work, but there was still only old version in my DB.

I think that the problem is caused by triggers connected with the procedure.

Do I have to 1. remove all of the triggers (over 80 tables => 80 triggers :( ), 2. replace procedure with new version, 3. re-create triggers?

Or is there another way to make "force replace"?

DBMS: PostgreSQL 9.2.6

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do is to remove "raise notice" line - seems to be simple, but it is not.. I tried to insert new procedure to database without the line, thinking that "create od REPLACE" would do the work, but there was still only old version in my DB.

Nope. Either you've installed the new function in the wrong database, wrong schema, with a typo in the name, failed to commit the change or missed an error message.

I replace trigger functions frequently and they're no different to any other function - `CREATE OR REPLACE` works just fine.

Comment: I'm sure that db, schema etc. are correct. Still the same problem. Strange.

Comment: Put together a self contained example that shows the problem and it would count as a bug. My guess is you won't be able to reproduce it.